# When running EXPLAIN, if the field value for key is not null but Extra is blank, is the key used?

Tags: mysql

When running this `EXPLAIN` query without an index

```
EXPLAIN SELECT exec_date,
    100 * SUM(CASE WHEN cached = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  / SUM(1) cached_no,
    100 * SUM(CASE WHEN cached != 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  / SUM(1) cached_yes
FROM requests
GROUP BY exec_date
```

This is the output

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      requests    ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL    478619  Using temporary; Using filesort
```

If I create an index

```
ALTER TABLE requests ADD INDEX exec_date(exec_date);
```

The output is

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      requests    index   NULL            exec_date   4       NULL    497847
```

Since the value of `Extra` is blank, does that mean the key `exec_date` is not being used?

On a test server, the execution time of the actual (not the `EXPLAIN` statement) query with and without the index is the same.

Comment: Is your question about why it doesn't say `Using index;`?

Comment: @Asad My question is if the value under `key` is `exec_date` but under `Extra` it doesn't say `Using index` does that mean the key is not going to be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Using index` doesn't mean what you think it means. If it is present in the `Extra` column, it indicates that the optimizer isn't actually reading the entire rows, it is using the index (exclusively) to find column information.

The key could still be in use for other things, for example to perform lookups if you have a `WHERE` clause etc. In your specific scenario, for example, the disappearance of the `Using temporary;` actually does mean that your index is being utilized, since MySQL no longer needs to rearrange the contents of your table into a new temporary table to perform the `GROUP BY`.