# How to create a temporary table

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which does not take advantage of the primary key on `request_id`

```
SELECT request_id, exec_datetime FROM requests
WHERE request_id mod 1000 = 1;
```

I was hoping to achieve some optimization by creating a temporary table that starts with the value 1 and increments by 1000 all the way up to 1,000,000 so that I may perform something like this

```
SELECT request_id, exec_datetime FROM requests
WHERE request_id IN (SELECT id FROM table);
```

Is there a syntax I can use to generate this table on the fly or do I actually have to create this table?

**EDIT**

I noticed the query executes about 8x faster with this workaround

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
thousand INT(10) UNSIGNED,
UNIQUE(thousand)
);

INSERT INTO dummy (SELECT request_id FROM requests WHERE request_id mod 1000=1 );

SELECT r.request_id, r.exec_datetime FROM requests r
JOIN dummy d
ON d.thousand = r.request_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a syntax to generate values like that for mysql (other databases eg postgres *do* have such a syntax). If there was, a *join* would perform better than an `IN`.

However, I would use your first query every time, unless there's evidence that it performs unacceptably poorly.

Comment: I see... If you interested in the performance difference for my use case using your suggestion for joins, check out my edit!  Also - can you look at my other question I posted today? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557405/when-running-explain-if-the-field-value-for-key-is-not-null-but-extra-is-blank

Comment: Also - Is there a mysql syntax to insert every 1000 rows starting from 1 and up to 1 million?  Something like this `INSERT INTO dummy (SELECT request_id FROM requests WHERE request_id mod 1000=1 );` but the upper bound is defined by me instead of the maximum amount of rows in the `request` table?